# React-redux, connect function does not update the state with the new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using `Redux` as a `Flux` alternative and `React` for the view layer. My application's `React` and `Redux` are bound with `react-redux` `connect()` method. 
When running the application it dispatches the action when the components mounts and the redux returns the correct state. However the `redux-logger` logs in the console that the store has updated with the new state, in the component when checking `this.props.session` it still shows the old state. I am guessing that I'm not using the `connect` method correctly, however I can't define the issue with it as well. Does anyone have an idea whats going on?

**containers/App**

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchUserSession} from 'actions/SessionActions';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    const {dispatch, session} = this.props;
    dispatch(fetchUserSession());
    console.log(session);
    // logs:
    // Object {currentUserId: null, errorMessage: null, isSessionValid: null}

    // store is bound to window, and the initial state is ImmutabeJS object
    console.log(window.store.getState().session.toJS());
    // logs:
    // Object {currentUserId: null, errorMessage: null, isSessionValid: false}
    // as you might noticed the isSessionValid is changed to false
  }

  render() {
    // html here 
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    session: state.session.toJS()
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

**actions/Actions.js**

```
'use strict';

import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

export const SESSION_REQUEST = 'SESSION_REQUEST';
export const SESSION_SUCCESS = 'SESSION_SUCCESS';

export function requestSession() {
  return {
    type: SESSION_REQUEST
  };
}

export function receiveSession(user) {
  return {
    type: SESSION_REQUEST,
    user
  };
}

export function fetchUserSession() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestSession());
    return fetch(`http://localhost:5000/session`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 404) {
          dispatch(raiseSessionFailure(response));
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(userData => dispatch(receiveSession(userData)));
  };
}
```

**reducers/SessionReducer.js**

```
'use strict';
import {fromJS} from 'immutable';

// UPDATE!!!
// here is the initial state
const initialState = fromJS({
  currentUserId: null,
  errorMessage: null,
  isSessionValid: null
});

function sessionReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SESSION_REQUEST':
      return state.update('isSessionValid', () => false);
    case 'SESSION_SUCCESS':
      console.log('Reducer: SESSION_SUCCESS');
      return state;
    case 'SESSION_FAILURE':
      console.log('Reducer: SESSION_FAILURE');
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default sessionReducer;
```

reducers/RootReducer

```
'use strict';

import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import sessionReducer from 'reducers/SessionReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  session: sessionReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: can you show what your state looks like? I think because you're not combining the reducers it'll look just like the `initialState` can you also include this too?

Comment: Hi @Clarkie I updated the reducer and put well how I combine the reducers

Comment: have you tried getting it to work without using the immutableJS lib? I've only ever used redux with the [immutability helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) from react

Comment: What version of `redux` and `react-redux` are you running? There might have been issues in pre-1.0 versions.

Comment: I'm not sure that this relates directly to the issue you are having, but the way you are logging to the console in `componentWillMount` is guaranteed to log different results for the `session` prop and the `session` in the store. The call to `dispatch` will update the store synchronously, but you won't see a new `session` prop until after `componentWillMount` has completed. Can you verifying this by logging `this.props.session` in a `setTimeout` instead of immediately after the call to `dispatch`?

Comment: @lukewestby you are right. Inside the `componentWillMount` function there is always the initial state, despite the fact that the action is dispatched and reducer sets the new state, the props will still have the initial state and the component will be rendered with that initial state, but then it re-renders the component with the new state. Can you please answer this question, so I can accept your answer and close this issue? Thank you.

Comment: PS. @DanAbramov thank you very very very much for an amazing job with Redux.

Comment: Sorry @Clarkie the issue wasn't with `ImmutableJS` I was mistaken :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with the way the `session` variable is being logged from `props` and from the store. When you dispatch the action to update state it is synchronously updating the store, which is why you see that the store has been updated when you log it directly. However, react-redux won't be able to update props until the call to `componentWillMount` has completed and React has had a chance to catch up and rerender the component with the new state. If you dispatch the action in `componentWillMount` and log the `session` prop at a later time you will see that it has changed to reflect the action.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't change state in action handlers in reducer. Only `case` with other than `return state` code says `state.update('isSessionValid', () => false)` — what does it return? If it's the same object as previous state, redux wouldn't change anything because of immutability convention.

Comment: The `state` is `ImmutableJs` object and the `update` is the method that the class `Map` has. Here is the [full documentation](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/update). basically the `update` function will return new `Map` object with the `isSessionValid` to false, where initially it is `null`

Comment: @Max and in client code using this field, do you explicitly differentiate between null and false? Because both 'compute to false' in JavaScript, and this looks like possible trouble